# How to create a matplotlib bar chart with a threshold line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'd like to know how to create a matplotlib bar chart with a threshold line, the part of bars above threshold line should have red color, and the parts below the threshold line should be green. Please provide me a simple example, I couldn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make it a stacked bar chart, like in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html), but divide your data up into the parts above your threshold and the parts below. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some example data
threshold = 43.0
values = np.array([30., 87.3, 99.9, 3.33, 50.0])
x = range(len(values))

# split it up
above_threshold = np.maximum(values - threshold, 0)
below_threshold = np.minimum(values, threshold)

# and plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, below_threshold, 0.35, color="g")
ax.bar(x, above_threshold, 0.35, color="r",
        bottom=below_threshold)

# horizontal line indicating the threshold
ax.plot([0., 4.5], [threshold, threshold], "k--")

fig.savefig("look-ma_a-threshold-plot.png")
```

[image: Example plot showing the result of the code]

Comment: Thank you, but what if the threshold doesn't have same value everywhere, for example for x < 3 threshold is 50, and for x >=3 threshold is 70? Is it possible to draw the chart the same way I want?

Comment: Sure, just make `threshold` an array of your desired value, instead of a single value. You'd have to change the dashed line, though.

Comment: Why are `np.minimum` and `np.maximum` used here? Why not `mask = values < threshold` then use `values[mask]` and `values[~mask]` to select the below and above threshold values?

Comment: @Guimoute Your way selects all the values that are less than (or greater than) the threshold. I wanted to split each value into two parts: the part that's below the threshold and the part above, so I know what to plot in green and in red. Try out your version and mine and compare them line by line, you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 37):

You can simply use `axhline` like this. See this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline)

```
# For your case
plt.axhline(y=threshold,linewidth=1, color='k')

# Another example - You can also define xmin and xmax
plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5)
```