# Question about Dataframe ploting with Pandas on Jupyter with multiple colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

1 - My goal is to create a bar plot of grades (y axis) and students id (x axis).

2 - Add an extra column with the mean() of the grades in a different color.

What's the best way of doing it?

I could create the first part but when it comes to change the color of the following column (mean), I couldn't finish it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.read_excel('x.xlsx')
Felipe_stu = a['Teacher'] == 'Felipe'
Felipe_stu.plot(kind = 'bar', figsize = (20,5), color = 'gold')
```

Example of data (the first 10):

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrBMF.png)

Example of plot:

[image]

I've already tried to create a list with all the colors of the respective items on the plot.
Such as:

```
my_color = []
for c in range(0, len(Jorge_stu))
    my_color.append('gold')
my_color.append('blue')
```

So, I would make the last column (the mean) in the color that I chose (blue in this case). This didn't work.

Any ideas how can I put the mean column on my plot?

Is it a better option to add an extra column to the plot or to add it in the proper dataframe and afterwards plot it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Could you please insert some sample data please?

Comment: Can u show some dummy data, how the columns and rows are..

Comment: Just adding a horizontal line as in `plt.axhline(Felipe_stu['Notas'].mean())` would be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

U may need to do something like this:

[How to create a matplotlib bar chart with a threshold line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129606/how-to-create-a-matplotlib-bar-chart-with-a-threshold-line)

the threshold value in the above example, will be ur mean line, and that can be simply calculated with the df[score_column_name].mean()