# How to plot a line in zero value in a graphic bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've plotted this bar graphic:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(20, 15))
data.plot('MES',["DIFERENCIAS DE TEMPERATURA MÁXIMA"],kind='bar',rot=0, alpha=0.8, color='darkred', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax1)
data.plot('MES',["DIFERENCIAS DE TEMPERATURA MÍNIMA"], kind='bar',rot=0, alpha=0.8,color='navy', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax2)
data.plot('MES',["DIFERENCIAS DE PRECIPITACIÓN"],kind='bar',rot=0, alpha=0.8,color='turquoise', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax3)
```

[image]

I want to draw a black and thin line in 0 axis value to separate positive and negative bar values. I'm searching how to do that but i can't find it. Would you mind to help me?

I want something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ax.hlines(y=100, xmin=0, xmax=1, linewidth=1, color='black')` for each `ax` where you set different `xmin` and `xmax`?

Comment: @Frodnar just a black line in yaxis = 0 in every subplot

Comment: Hmm.  I thought that was your goal.  Clearly, I don't understand your question?  Could you describe in a different way (or visually on an image) where you want the line(s) to be?

Comment: Ok i will add an image

Comment: It's kind of weird but i could solve it with this :     `ax1.hlines(y=0, xmin=-1, xmax=12, linewidth=1, color='black')
    ax2.hlines(y=0, xmin=-1, xmax=12, linewidth=1, color='black')
    ax3.hlines(y=0, xmin=-1, xmax=12, linewidth=1, color='black')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure since I'm a new, but I believe if you did this it may work

```
# For your case
plt.axhline(y=threshold,linewidth=1, color='k')

# Another example - You can also define xmin and xmax
plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5)
```

I took this from [How to create a matplotlib bar chart with a threshold line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129606/how-to-create-a-matplotlib-bar-chart-with-a-threshold-line)

all credit to Abu Shoeb.