# How to make barplot with a threshold in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, threshold

I want to use the code provided below for a barplot, but with added threshold, where the data on or below the threshold have a color different to the data points above the threshold.

Please check out this link to understand what I mean with threshold in a barplot: [How to create a matplotlib bar chart with a threshold line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129606/how-to-create-a-matplotlib-bar-chart-with-a-threshold-line/75876068?noredirect=1#comment133836324_75876068)

I tried to use the suggested code in the link, but it's not working specially that I require the use of bar annotation.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
def plot_data(data_type, title, plot_name):
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    threshold = 5
    position = data_type["Position"]
    count = data_type["Count"]
    splot = sns.barplot(x=position, y=count, color="violet", data=data_type) 
    plt.axhline(y=threshold) #this shows a horizontal line starting from threshold
    plt.title(title, size=50)
    plt.xlabel("Positon", fontsize=30)
    plt.ylabel("Count", fontsize=30)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)

    for p in splot.patches:
        splot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.0f'), 
                       (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                       ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
                       size=20, xytext = (0, 8),
                       textcoords = 'offset points')
    plt.savefig(plot_name, format="png")  
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please point out why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129801/16521194) is not satisfactory to you?

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn doesn't do stacked bar plots.  But you can just draw the bars twice: once with their original height, and once with the height clipped to the threshold.  For the annotations, matplotlib now has a new `bar_label()` function.

Note that `sns.barplot` returns an `ax` (subplot) which you can use to make changes via matplotlib's [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some dummy data for testing
data_type = pd.DataFrame({"Position": np.arange(1, 31),
                          "Count": np.random.randint(1, 10, 30)})

plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
threshold = 5
position = data_type["Position"]
count = data_type["Count"]
ax = sns.barplot(x=position, y=count, color="violet")
sns.barplot(x=position, y=np.clip(count, a_min=0, a_max=threshold), color='turquoise', ax=ax)
ax.axhline(y=threshold, ls=':')  # this shows a horizontal line at the threshold
# ax.set_title("title", size=50)
ax.set_xlabel("Positon", fontsize=30)
ax.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=30)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], size=20)
sns.despine()

# plt.savefig(plot_name, format="png")
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with coloring up to a threshold]

PS: If you have more than one count per position, you'll first need to create an aggregated dataframe.

For example:

```
data_type = pd.DataFrame({"Position": np.random.randint(1, 31, 100),
                          "Count": np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)})
data_summed = data_type.groupby("Position").agg(sum).reset_index() # or agg(mean) or agg(max) or ....
```

and then use `data_summed` for the bar plots.

Comment: Thank you so much JohnC! But please help me with one more thing; I don't know where in the code you wrote, I can get the sum of count instead of the average? In my dataset, some positions have more than one count, and for some reason I get the average of the count when running your code, but I want the SUM of count.

Comment: Normally, you would use `sns.barplot(..., estimator=sum, errorbar=None)`. But that doesn't go together with the call to `np.clip()`.  Here you'll need to create a new dataframe with the sums and plot that.

Comment: I updated the post with example code for summing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
splot = sns.barplot(x=[position <= threshold], 
                    y=[count <= threshold] , color="violet", data=data_type)
```

Comment: Did you test this? The code doesn't make sense. And it doesn't address the coloring issue in the question.